# how to convert flatbuffer .fbs file to .bin file

Tags: flatbuffers

i am learning [flatbuffers in java](http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html)
I want to create a .bin file from .fbs file and I don't have `.json` file already how do i create a json file so that I can create a bin file?

as they already had `mosterdata.json` file in thier sample code but what if we don't have the JSON file? and we just had the `.fbs` file and it's generated java code only?
[as mentioned here](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_using_schema_compiler.html) how will i get the data file ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make your `.bin` file.

1. Use JSON to specify the contents.

   ```
   flatc -b <your_schema.fbs> <your_data.json>
   ```

   Where `-b` means generate a binary file.

   To make `your_data.json` you'll have to make it yourself, using `your_schema.fbs` to guide you on how to specify the json fields. I would check out how the [`monsterdata_test.json`](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/tests/monsterdata_test.json) is specified by its corresponding schema [`monster_test.fbs`](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/tests/monster_test.fbs)

2. Use `flatc` to output the Java code gen, and then programmatically generate the `.bin` using the generated code.

   ```
   flatc --java <your_schema.fbs>
   ```

   This way is a lot more involved, since you have to make a program that uses the generated code and output the binary yourself. Check out the [tutorial](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html) (switch to the java language) for example usage.

Comment: many thanks, i have done this via java code and write the bin file to a disk